# PSD full of lines

Tags: photoshop

[image]

Anybody know what this is about? (I'm on a PC, btw - I'm not sure if it has to do with that?)

Comment: Answer: Not about programming.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the fact that these are guides, and this question is not about programming (check the footer of this site, there's several other sites in this format for questions that are not about programming, such as [graphics design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)), **your PSD file looks corrupted**.

I'm guessing a bad transfer or something. Ask the guy who sent you that to send it again, maybe.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was suspecting... :)

Comment: I've had this happen once before and it was when a guy with a mac sent it to me zipped...

Comment: @user1775718 what do you mean "above"? If it's the case of a corrupted zip, in any case Photoshop is still showing the corrupted data as guides. Guides in Photoshop are those cyan strips - they're used for aligning stuff. It's common for web designers to use those since you can snap stuff to them (therefore keeping far away things aligned, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Go to the view menu and uncheck "extras" :) These are the "guides" that can help you with things like alignment.

Answer (score 0):

or press Ctrl + H. Those are guiding lines for your help to better know the coordinates or whatever you want them to be for. You can add them by clicking on the ruler and draging mouse towards your image.